# how does browser (firefox/safari) detects that website you are visiting is infected?

Tags: browser, virus

how does browser (firefox/safari) detects that website you are visiting is infected?

Do they have a black list? or they run the URL through some Antivirus scripts? or What happens behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each browser manufacturer maintains its own blacklist. See:

- http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/phishing-protection/
- http://www.microsoft.com/security/filters/smartscreen.aspx